# plurals with and without a definite article in a relative clause

Tags: definite-article, relative-clauses, plural-forms

My understanding of plurals with and without a definite article in a relative clause is given:

*tribes: all tribes*

*the tribes: Some specific set of tribes*

But the following sentences confuse me:

> He found among them an implicit sense of order and design, even among **tribes** who practised ruthless warfare.

My understanding: some of the tribes who practised ruthless warfare.

> He found among them an implicit sense of order and design, even among **the tribes** who practised ruthless warfare.

My understanding: all the tribes who practised ruthless warfare.

This is directly opposite of my understanding of plurals and plurals with definite articles.

From: [Claude Lévi-Strauss, 100, Dies; Altered Western Views of the ‘Primitive’](https://www.nytimes.com/2009/11/04/world/europe/04levistrauss.html)

Comment: Your understanding isn't quite right. It's not ***some of** the tribes who practised ruthless warfare*. It's ***those** tribes who practised ruthless warfare*. In principle, that's ***all those tribes***, but obviously the writer isn't likely to know about every single one of those tribes anyway, so don't treat it *too* literally.

Comment: Just 'tribes' without 'the' before could be some (but not necessarily all) of those tribes who practised ruthless warfare.

Comment: Actually, the text as cited is ambiguous between whether it's ***all*** (warring tribes known to the writer) or just ***at least one of them*** (exhibiting an implicit sense of order and design that the writer could "find") OR anywhere in between those limits. It's not worth spending time on the ambiguity, though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If the writer had known all the tribes  who practised ruthless warfare, he would have written **the tribes**?

Comment: No. Almost certainly the writer himself couldn't know for sure whether he knew all the tribes - and even if he did, that's information which is unlikely to be worth trying to include "peripherally" through the exact way of phrasing his reference to them. For all practical purposes, the only possible situations are 1) The writer is sure ***all*** warring tribes are "ordered" (the same as he's sure about that for all non-warring tribes), OR 2) Writer has found ***at least one*** "ordered" warring tribe, but doesn't necessarily think/know they're ***all*** like that...

Comment: It makes no difference if he uses ***the*** or ***those*** or ***<nothing>*** - all those imply case 1. Case 2 is implied by ***some** tribes*. So ***some*** ENTAILS ***not all***,  the others all IMPLY ***all*** (in such contexts, "entails" means "must be true", "implies" means "**probably** true").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before we get into the answer, **all nouns** that are modified by a *defining relative clause* (like both your examples) **refer to some specific set** of that noun because the function of defining relative clause is to specify a subset from among a larger set.

When referring to a noun modified by a defining relative clause, the only difference between using "the" and *zero article* is that using "the" implies contrast with some other set. Without "the", it is merely a noun phrase, and nothing is implied about any other set.

The same applies to simple adjectives, not just to defining relative clauses:

> Vultures eat dead animals.
> Vultures eat the dead animals.

The second sentence suggests a contrast with living animals, while the first has no such nuance.

In your examples, there's really no difference in meaning, because in that context, by mentioning that warring subset of tribes with "even", the author assumes the reader has already imagined the subset of comparatively peaceful tribes, so with or without "the", the contrast is clear.

Where "the" or no "the" does make a difference is where the subset doesn't imply any other subset. For instance:

> *(a hiring  manager speaking to staff)* We're looking for job applicants [who have at least a Bachelors Degree, 5 years' experience working in a technical field, and can demonstrate excellent communicative skills].

This sentence without any other context doesn't imply contrast with any other sets of applicants because there's no "the". But with "the", it implies some other set of applicants:

> **OK, we've sorted out all the unqualified candidates**, so now we're looking for **the** job applicants who have at least a Bachelors Degree, 5 years' experience working in a technical field, and can demonstrate excellent communicative skills.

Again, "the" isn't required here, but this is an example where it makes sense to use it to emphasize the contrast with the previous activity.

Comment: Is the reason for **the** in the *the job applicants* that we have a set of applicants who are identified as the qualified candidates and to specify we are talking only about the qualified candidates? Whereas in the first case, we didn't have any applicants.

Comment: @Englishified In this story, the staff were first looking for unqualified candidates to remove them. Now, the focus has changed, and the new set we're looking for is candidates with specific qualifications. The reason for "the" is to contrast this new set of candidates with the old set that they had been looking for.